# iPhone Prevent application to automatically change orientation to portrait when a video stop

Tags: iphone, video, orientation, mpmovieplayercontroller

My application is in landscape mode and I use **MPMoviePlayerController** to play an sample video. It works fine but when I stop the video with the **OK** button (or if I wait until the movie ends), the orientation automatically changes to portrait. 
Is it possible to keep application in landscape mode when the OK button is pushed ?

I use the followwing code in my main view controller to force landscape mode :

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think on the MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification notification you have to set the statusbarorientation back to landscape.