# Change Orientation back to Portrait

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.6

When using my app users can click and watch videos displayed in a list. Once they click on that video they can change the orientation to either portrait or landscape. The list page is only portrait.

The error I am facing is when the user watch's a video in landscape and exits the page in landscape my list page become all messed up.

I need a way to turn the orientation back to portrait every time the user presses done on the video and returns back to the list.

On the list page I do have

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
  return YES;
}
```

And I even tried to call `shouldAutorotate` method in the viewDidAppear but that doesn't work. I know that `shouldAutorotate` is not being called after the page is loaded so is there a way to check the orientation then flip it or just make it portrait no matter what?

I still need landscape so I am not going to remove it from my plist file.

Any help would be great. Thanks

EDIT

Here is how I call my video player

```
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *player=[[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[main_data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"url"]]];

    UIView * playerView = [player view];
    [playerView setFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320)];

    CGAffineTransform landscapeTransform;
    landscapeTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(90*M_PI/180.0f);
    landscapeTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(landscapeTransform, 80, 80);

    [playerView setTransform: landscapeTransform];

    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:player];

    return;
```

Comment: Perhaps this question could help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324745/iphone-prevent-application-to-automatically-change-orientation-to-portrait-when?rq=1

Comment: How is the transition from the video list to the video done? Modally, or some other way?

Comment: Never call shouldAutorotate yourself. It's not a method for you to call; only the system should do that. Calling it yourself won't do anything.

Comment: I have added how I call the video. I kinda figured I shouldn't call that method but I need it to switch to portrait.

Comment: Are you targeting iOS 6? Part of your issue may be that you are using rotation methods from a different iOS version but targeting the newest version, in which rotation has changed.

Comment: I am using `shouldAutorotate` everywhere and that is for iOS 6.0.

Comment: `(BOOL)shouldAutorotate` should just return YES or no - you also need to combine it with `(NSInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations` as Seamus has pointed out below. 

However, I do believe that your issue lies somewhere else. There is an old method I used once upon a time as follows: `[UIViewController attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation]`. See if that works somewhere when you pop the player from the view stack.

Comment: I tried calling that in my viewDidAppear method. Is that a good place to call this? I have never used that

Comment: please check this it will surely help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014176/mpmoviewplayercontroller-fullscreen-playback-rotation-with-underlying-uiviewcont

Comment: Try adding the orientation you want by calling the orientation mask in the same method where you call the video done. Once the video is done then in your movie player method after declaring it then input the view orientation. See if you that helps you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several approaches available to you. Perhaps the simplest and most controllable is to subclass of `MPMoviePlayerViewController`.

Start by having your *app* support ALL interface orientations (in the `app-info.plist`). Then restrict your *list view* (let's assume it's `MyListViewController.m`) to portrait with methods for both iOS 6 and earlier operating systems:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
 return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations {
 return(UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait);
}

- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate {
 return FALSE;   
}
```

Now create a new Objective C class derived from `MPMoviePlayerViewController`, called `MyMoviePlayerViewController`. Here's `MyMoviePlayerViewController.h`:

```
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

@interface MyMoviePlayerViewController : MPMoviePlayerViewController

@end
```

And here's `MyMoviePlayerViewController.m`:

```
#import "MyMoviePlayerViewController.h"

@interface MyMoviePlayerViewController ()
@end

@implementation MyMoviePlayerViewController

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
 return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations {
 return(UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll);
}

- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate {
 return TRUE;    
}

-(id)initWithContentURL:(NSURL *)contentURL {
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(1,1));
 self = [super initWithContentURL:contentURL];
 UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
 if (self) {
    self.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
            name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
            object:[self moviePlayer]];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
            selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:)
            name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
            object:[self moviePlayer]];
 }
 return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
[[self moviePlayer] setFullscreen:YES animated:NO];
[self moviePlayer].controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
}

- (void)movieFinishedCallback:(NSNotification*)notification {
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [notification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
        name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
        object:moviePlayer];
    self.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
@end
```

Then, add to `MyListViewController.h`:

```
#import "MyMoviePlayerViewController.h"
```

And, in `MyListViewController.m`, use:

```
MyMoviePlayerViewController *player =[[MyMoviePlayerViewController alloc]
    initWithContentURL:URLWithString:[[main_data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
    objectForKey:@"url"]]];
[self presentViewController:player animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Obviously, you can tweak the settings (such as animation styles, controls to display...) to suite your specific needs.

Comment: This solution worked best for me. Want to work out some things but overall good solution

Answer (score 2):

On iOS 6, the mechanisms for autorotation behavior have changed, so if you're testing on an iOS 6 device, you'll need a little extra work.  In your view controller, add the following method:

```
-(NSInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Comment: I have added this and it does get called when I first view the page. When I go into the video, change the orientation, then go back to that page both the `shouldAutorotate` and `supportedInterfaceOrientations` are not being called.

Comment: It is because you are popping it from the view stack (modally), and thus the system has no reason to call it

Comment: I checked again and `shouldAutorotate` is not being called the first time (I confused it with another break point). Is there a reason why its not being called in the first place. Is it because the system doesn't know its in the view stack?

Comment: How are you presenting your first view controller?  Are you using the `window.rootViewController` property, or the older method of just adding the view controller's view as a subview of the window?

Comment: I'm wondering here why the system wouldn't know that your view controller is in the view stack.

Comment: I am adding the view controller view as a subview of the window

Comment: You should definitely be setting the rootViewController instead.

Comment: Ok so I set it the way you have described. To let ou know I have both a navigation controller and a tab controller. I assume that I am setting the tab controller, which is the bottom tab bar, to the root and the navigation controlller, which is the tab content, to a subview of that

Answer (score 0):

What about calling `[UIViewController attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation]` when your video controller is hidden?

Comment: I tried calling that in my `viewDidAppear` method. Is that a good place to call this? I have never used that

Answer (score 0):

Implement this in your list view controller

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
  return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ;
}
```

-anoop

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

In your viewdidLoad method write this line to support orientation in app,

```
//rotation
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged) name:@"UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification" object:nil];



#pragma mark -Rotation
//method for rotate your playerview, as user changes orientation
-(void)orientationChanged 
{
    NSLog(@"Orientation Changed..!!");
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.35];
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)  {
        playerView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0);
    }
    else if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        playerView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
    }
    else if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)  {
        playerView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI+(M_PI/2));
    }
   else if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)        {
        playerView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
    }
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

#ifdef IOS_OLDER_THAN_6
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:   (UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
#endif

// For Newer than IOS 6.
#ifdef IOS_NEWER_OR_EQUAL_TO_6
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait);
}
#endif
```

Hope this helps., Thnak you.. happy coding

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to write the code below code in `- (void)movieFinishedCallback:(NSNotification*)notification`

```
- (void)movieFinishedCallback:(NSNotification*)notification 
{
    [self.view setFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    CGAffineTransform landscapeTransform;
    landscapeTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(270*M_PI/180.0f);
    landscapeTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(landscapeTransform, 80, 80);
    [self.view setTransform: landscapeTransform];
}
```