# MPMoviePlayer in multiple orientation

Tags: iphone, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

In my ViewController i'm placing `MPMoviePlayerController` to play video. It was working fine.  It was able to play in full screen mode too. Now, i'm in need to play this movie in *Landscape right* and *Landscape left* also. How do i achieve this? And, the important note is my app will support only on *Portrait* mode. I just want to display this movie player in both directions. How do i do that? Any idea appreciable!

Here is my code -

```
-(void)playMovie
{
    NSString *movieURL = ___;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:movieURL];
    player =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:url];
    self._moviePlayer = player;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:_moviePlayer];

    _moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
    _moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;

    _moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(10, shortDesc.frame.origin.y+shortDesc.frame.size.height+10, 280,150);

    [_moviePlayer play];
}


- (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    player = [notification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:player];

    if ([player respondsToSelector:@selector(setFullscreen:animated:)])    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have answered this here, with code: [Change Orientation back to Portrait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15550797/change-orientation-back-to-portrait/15703012#15703012)

You have an *app* that supports all orientations, a *main view controller* that only supports portrait, and a *subclassed* `MPMoviePlayerController` that supports all orientations (or all, but upside down, or landscape only, or whatever you want...).